# File Writer Delimiter Problem throws an Exception after scanning 1st line

Tags: java, filereader

So I have this problem here I am trying to use the Delimiter "," so that I can make it so that I can make
use space and it will not recognize that space as the delimiter

```
public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File file = new File("Project.txt");
        Scanner reader2 = new Scanner(file);
        reader2.useDelimiter(",");
        String wholeFile = "";
        String ID = "";
        String Name = "";
        String Birthday = "";
        String Gender = "";
        String Age = "";
        String CNumber = "";
        while(reader2.hasNext())
        {
            ID = reader2.next();
            Name = reader2.next();
            Birthday = reader2.next();
            Gender = reader2.next();
            Age = reader2.next();
            CNumber = reader2.next();
            wholeFile = wholeFile+(ID+" "+Name+" "+Birthday+" "+Gender+" "+Age+" "+CNumber+"\n");
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, wholeFile);
        
        JFrame frame= new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        frame.add(panel);
        
        JTextArea tf = new JTextArea(wholeFile);
        tf.setBounds(30, 30, 400, 400);
        panel.add(tf);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    
    }

}
```

and the file "Project.txt"

```
1,Ron,September,Male,19,09567369293
2,Ron,September,Male,19,09567369293
```

problem is it works perfectly on the 1st line but in the next it will throw an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
    at Test2.main(Test2.java:32)
```

and if I use the space " " as the delimiter it works fine too... please help me how I can use this
Delimiter "," instead of " " without it throwing an exception even though I think it should work fine.

And I am using JOptionPane and GUI just to compare so please don't mind it, should probably have nothing to do with my problem

Comment: Take care of java naming conventzions. variable names should start with lower case character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is CNumber and ID are combined to gather and consider as single. Because you not define the **\n** in delimiter pattern.

Change as below,

`reader2.useDelimiter(",|\n");`